# Regarding Hadoop failure and new HBase?

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I have 2 questions:

```
1. Is NameNode still single point of failure in Hadoop YARN or new version of Hadoop e.g. 2.5?
```

What is the single point of failure in Hadoop?

```
2.  I saw Facebook is using HydraBase. Is HydraBase new version Hbase or is it new DBMS similar to Hbase?
```

Does HydraBase have Apache version or is it open source?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answring your first question :

A single point of failure is a part of the system, if it fails, the complete systems will be unavailable. SPOF can be avoided by adding redundancy in all potential SPOFs.

HDFS and YARN(MR2) are the core components of Hadoop, In HDFS namenode was SPOF, but with the introduciton of Namnode HA (2 namenodes One active and One standby) namenode is not SPOF anymore. You can configure Namenode HA in Hadoop 2.5

In YARN, Resource manager was SPOF but HA can be configured for Hadoop version 2.3 onwards.

Answer to second question

*Hydrabase*

Hydrabase is a souped up version of Hbase, but this will be a separate NOSQL protect.

What makes HydraBase better than HBase is that it is supposedly a more reliable database that should minimize downtime when servers fail.If a region server goes down, all the regions it hosts have to migrate to another region server. According to Facebook, although HBase has automatic failover, it can take a long time to actually happen.

As of now Hydrabase is not open source, However facebook is going to release it under Apache Projects (Open source). It's apache version will be released in 5 months, Visit [site](http://hydrabase.org/) for the exact release date

Comment: So is there any single point of failure in current latest Hadoop?

Comment: No SPOFs for HDFS, YARN, MR1 in Hadoop 2.5